# How can I construct an image out of select pixels on it?

Tags: java, image, arrays

I have an .lfp image that is a grid of circles, each circle encapsulating around 20x20 pixels, much like can be seen in [this zoomed in version](http://eclecti.cc/computervision/reverse-engineering-the-lytro-lfp-file-format). I want be able to select the same pixel for each circle and construct a new image out of these. So for example, I would take the center pixel of every circle, and make a picture out these.

I have this basic code that turns the jpeg image into a byte array, but since I don't fully understand how the byte array stores the pixels, nor in what order, I don't know how to select the desired pixels. Furthermore, once I have selected them, how do I concatenate them into a new image?

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;


public class SimpleConvertImage {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  String dirName="./";
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
  BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File(dirName,"plants.jpg"));
  ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
  baos.flush();

  String base64String=Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
  baos.close();

  byte[] bytearray = Base64.decode(base64String);
  for (int i = 0; i < bytearray.length/2; i++) {
      byte t = bytearray[i];
      bytearray[i] = bytearray[bytearray.length - 1 - i];
      bytearray[bytearray.length - 1 - i] = t;
  }

  BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray));
  ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", new File(dirName,"plantJava.jpg"));
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are going to end up with a few thousand images, each 20x20, yes? And you want to do it in Java? And what libraries are you planning to use - OpenCV? ImageMagick? Is your problem locating the centres, or extracting the 20x20 or which aspect is troubling you?

Comment: Have you got, or can you make, a sample output image?